# Is It possible to inject a scope variable from a controller into a service function Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
angular.module('store_locator')
        .constant("baseURL","http://locator.sas.dev.atcsp.co.za/api/")
        .service('stationsService', ['$http', 'baseURL', function($http,baseURL) {

          this.getStations = function(){
              return $http.get(baseURL+"station.json");
          };

          this.getStation = function (index) {
            return $http.get(baseURL+"station/"+index+".json");
          };

        }]);
```

I have here a service with 2 functions, I need to amend the getStations function in some way to allow the usage of the below:

```
$scope.filterList = [];
$scope.change = function(subproduct, active){
      if (active){
          $scope.filterList.push(subproduct.subproduct_id);
          $scope.filterPush = "?subproducts[]="+$scope.filterList.join("&subproducts[]=");
        }
      else{
          $scope.filterList.splice($scope.filterList.indexOf(subproduct), 1);
          $scope.filterPush = "?subproducts[]="+$scope.filterList.join("&subproducts[]=");
        }
};
```

I need to append the `$scope.filterList` here:

```
return $http.get(baseURL+"station.json"+$scope.filterList);
```

The reason for this is that i have to do a new $http call on submit of a search button. I hope I'm descriptive enough.

Comment: You *cannot* use a scope from a service directly, but you can pass the desired scope data as arguments to the service method.

Comment: Could You please possibly give me an example? im quite new to angular

Comment: `this.getStations = function(filterList){return $http.get(baseURL+"station.json"+filterList);}` and call it from the controller as `stationsService.getStations($scope.filterList)`

Comment: @Pratik answers is right however it doesn't explain why you can't inject $scope in a service. It's because each controller are given a unique $scope instance which inherits from another or $rootScope. So unlike all services/controller, $scope is not a singleton. So you can't inject it in a service layer which is not bound to a controller/route/state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You cannot inject $scope in your service. Expose the desired method in your service and pass the required data (which is in your scope) as an argument. Call the service method from your change method in the controller.

**Service**

```
this.getStations = function(filterList){
              return $http.get(baseURL+"station.json"+filterList);
          };
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.change = function(subproduct, active){
        if (active){
            $scope.filterList.push(subproduct.subproduct_id);
            $scope.filterPush = "?subproducts[]="+$scope.filterList.join("&subproducts[]=");
          }
        else{
            $scope.filterList.splice($scope.filterList.indexOf(subproduct), 1);
            $scope.filterPush = "?subproducts[]="+$scope.filterList.join("&subproducts[]=");
          }
stationsService.getStations($scope.filterList);
}
```